# by.css always returns null [jasmine unit test ]

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-unit-test

I have no idea why in my Angular project, Jasmin alwasys return null when I'm trying to access a HTML's element!

```
it('should find the <p> with fixture.debugElement.query(By.css)', () => {
    const bannerDe: DebugElement = fixture.debugElement;
    const paragraphDe = bannerDe.query(By.css('p'));
    const p: HTMLElement = paragraphDe.nativeElement;
    expect(p.textContent).toEqual('banner works!');
  });
```

```
<p class="title">banner works!</p>
```

I also have tried to call 'fixture.whenStable().then' but again it returns null!

```
it('should find the <p> with fixture.debugElement.query(By.css)', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MobileAppLinkComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
    const bannerDe: DebugElement = fixture.debugElement;
    const paragraphDe = bannerDe.query(By.css('p'));
    const p: HTMLElement = paragraphDe.nativeElement;
    expect(p.textContent).toEqual('banner works!');
    })
```

Comment: does the `By.css('p')` return null or the `bannerDe.query(By.css('p'))`?

Comment: bannerDe.query(By.css('p')) returns null &  By.css('p') returns debugElement with length 1

Comment: Do you import the correct `By` class from `@angular/platform-browser`

Comment: Yeah I do. I’ve used @angular/platform-browser

Comment: I used commonjs in our tsconfig:{
 "compileOnSave": false,
 "compilerOptions": {
  "baseUrl": "./",
  "target": "es5",
  "module": "commonjs",
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "sourceMap": true,
  "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
  "lib": ["es2017", "dom"],
  "noImplicitAny": false,
  "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
 }
}

Answer (score 3):

Most likely the `p` tag is hidden by an `*ngIf`. Can you try logging out the `fixture.nativeElement` to see if you see the `p` tag?

```
it('should find the <p> with fixture.debugElement.query(By.css)', () => {
    const bannerDe: DebugElement = fixture.debugElement;
    // !! Add this line to see if the p tag is there
    console.log(fixture.nativeElement);
    const paragraphDe = bannerDe.query(By.css('p'));
    const p: HTMLElement = paragraphDe.nativeElement;
    expect(p.textContent).toEqual('banner works!');
  });
```

If the `p` tag is not there, most likely it is being hidden by an `*ngIf` by a parent element. You will have to make this condition true, then `fixture.detectChanges()` so the HTML updates and then attempt to grab the `p` tag with `fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('p'))`.

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out that my module in compilerOptions was commonjs in tsConfig.ts so I've updated it to es2020 and it worked as expected.

{
"compileOnSave": false,
"compilerOptions": {
"baseUrl": "./",
"target": "es5",
"module": "es2020",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"sourceMap": true,
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true
}
}